# Django foreign key in model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, foreign-keys

I am doing a project so created one model and imported all data to django admin so my table looks like this

```
Dates          Sr no   Symbol      Series    Qty
Oct. 19, 2013   245    ZYDUSWELL    EQ      5
Oct. 19, 2013,  244    ZEEL         EQ      96
Oct. 19, 2013,  243    YESBANK      EQ      74
Oct. 19, 2013,  242    WIPRO        EQ      65
```

I have created another one table which describe the full form of column symbol but the client need to display the full form instead of the displayed symbol in the above table how can I achieve this this my code

The model for given table

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    dates = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
    sr_no = models.IntegerField(editable=False,null=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=False)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=False,null=True)
    qty = models.IntegerField(editable=False,null=True)
```

The model contains full form of symbol

```
class Sttlmnt_typ_Master(models.Model): 
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10, editable=False)
    symbol_name =  models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=False)
```

-----kindly please help me.......!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to have `symbol` field as the foreign key to `Sttlmnt_typ_Master`.

But if you sure want models like this then add this method to you `ModelAdmin`:

```
class AuctionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('dates', 'sr_no', 'symbol_display', 'series', 'qty')

    def symbol_display(self, obj):
        symbol = Sttlmnt_typ_Master.objects.filter(symbol=obj.symbol).first()
        return symbol.symbol_name if symbol else obj.symbol
    symbol_display.short_description = 'Symbol'
```

This will work but filtering `Sttlmnt_typ_Master` for every row in admin is very inefficient.  You should consider to switch to "foreign key" option.

**EDIT**: Foreign key option.

Add the `__unicode__`  method to `Sttlmnt_typ_Master` model and change `Auction.symbol` field to `ForeignKey`:

```
class Sttlmnt_typ_Master(models.Model): 
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10, editable=False)
    symbol_name =  models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.symbol_name

class Auction(models.Model):
    dates = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
    sr_no = models.IntegerField(editable=False, null=True)
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Sttlmnt_typ_Master, editable=False)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=False, null=True)
    qty = models.IntegerField(editable=False, null=True)
```

Now changelist in admin will display `symbol` field with `symbol_name` property.  Django admin is smart enough to add `select_related('symbol')` to queryset so there will be no additional queries to database.

Of course you should change your import function to populate `Auction.symbol` fields with valid `Sttlmnt_typ_Master` instances instead of plain text.

**EDIT2**: Populating `Auction.symbol` field.

```
symbol = 'ZYDUSWELL'
auction.symbol, created = Sttlmnt_typ_Master.objects.get_or_create(
                             symbol=symbol, defaults={'symbol_name': symbol})
```

[See the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Comment: how i can implement it using foriegn key can you please give me an eaxample

Comment: The first code  simply working fine and thanks for your valuable information

Comment: i didn’t understand the foreign key implementation, can you help me. After applying the above code what all things should be done in admin.py @catavaran

Comment: You don't need to change the admin. Then admin display foreign key `symbol` field it automatically calls `__unicode__` method of this field.

Comment: @sudeepkrishnan the thing to change is your import code.  It should `get_or_create` valid `Sttlmnt_typ_Master` instance and assign it to `symbol` field.

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance I am new to django and python can you show me an example